# default.xml in my custom module isn't working

Tags: magento2, layout

I'm trying to add custom template from my custom module.

Layout file: app/code/Foo/Bar/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Foo\Bar\Block\FooterTest" name="footer_assets" template="footer/test.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

my template: app/code/Foo/Bar/view/frontend/templates/footer/test.phtml

```
<span>test</span>
```

When i rename layout file from default.xml to cms_index_index.xml then template is displayed, but only on home page. What i have to change to display this template on all pages?

Answer (score 1):

In you default.xml you can add `after="footer_links"` and mention your module template like `"Foo_Bar::footer/test.phtml"`

I have tried below code and working fine for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="footer">
        <block class="Foo\Bar\Block\FooterTest"  name="footer_assets" after="footer_links" template="Foo_Bar::footer/test.phtml"/>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Hope this answer will help.

Answer (score 0):

Change default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Foo\Bar\Block\FooterTest" name="footer_assets" template="Foo_Bar::footer/test.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And make sure your block class is [Foo\Bar\Block\FooterTest.php]

```
namespace Foo\Bar\Block;

class FooterTest extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@krishna ijjada  @Sohel Rana thx for help but cause was in another place. First i tried add this template in my custom theme and then i was added it by module. When i removed it from default.xml in theme then it has been started work by my module.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make it work certainly in controller/action class example View.php with execute() method return block and layout specific.try this with may example :

```
`<?php
```

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MageMastery\FirstLayout\Controller\Page;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;

class View extends Action
{
public function execute()
{
/** @var Page $resultPage */
// var_dump($this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE));
$page = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
$block = $page->getLayout('default')->getBlock('magemastery.first.layout.example.custom');
$block->setData('custom-param', 'Data from Controller');
return $page;
}

}
`

Answer (score 0):

Please create a file like below structure for proper out.

```
view/adminhtml/layout/routeid_controller_index.xml
```