# Override parent templates from custom module page

Tags: magento2

I created a custom landing page module for our store.

```
app/code/<Company>/Landing
```

It has the following directory structure, but I am having a really hard time figuring out how to integrate it into the overall site.

[image]

For example, how am I supposed to apply a theme to the pages served by this module?

Most importantly though, **how do I modify the layout of this page**? I have tried using the `<referenceBlock name="name" remove="true"/>` pattern but cannot figure out where to put. A lot of posts mention [default.xml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127861/default-xml-in-my-custom-module-isnt-working), but where would I locate this file in the directory structure?

[image]
For example, I want to remove these templates from the page. It would seem that they are located in the `<referenceContainer name="header.container">` tag, so I have tried adding: `<referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true">` tag but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own `default.xml` and put it in `app/code/<Company>/Landing/view/frontend/layout` like this.

[image]

Any update in `default.xml` will affect all your frontend pages.
E.g., you want to remove `header.container` from all pages. Your `default.xml` can be like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

**UPDATE**: You totally can do it with specific page, by create xml file for specific request. E.g., To add static css file for `checkout/cart/index` page, create `checkout_cart_index.xml` in `app/code/<Company>/Landing/view/frontend/layout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="path/to/css-file.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ahh I see, so I can't do it page specific in that case. What I've decided to try doing is to serve static CSS to this page only which will turn off the display attribute for all of those HTML elements...

Comment: @DanielThompson please see my updated answer

Comment: very helpful, thank you! Didn't realize you could do that with layout files.